# Linear regression, gradient descent not working for some values

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have implemented linear regression with gradient descent but it doesn't work when I need to get decreasing function or constant function.

It works for data like

```
x_train = np.array([30,60,70,100])
y_train= np.array([60,120,145,195])
```

where I need to get increasing function like here `f(x_train) ≈ 2*x_train=y_train` or for data like

```
x_train = np.array([30,60,70,100])
y_train= np.array([30,60,70,100])
```

where is `f(x_train)=x_train=y_train`, but it doesn't work for data like this

```
x_train = np.array([50,100,150,200])
y_train= np.array([150,100,50,0])
```

decreasing function `f(x_train)=200-x_train=y_train` or for constant function `f(x_train)=100=y_train`

```
x_train = np.array([50,100,150,200])
y_train= np.array([100,100,100,100])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#doesnt work
#x_train = np.array([50,100,150,200])
#y_train= np.array([150,100,50,0])

#work
x_train = np.array([30,60,70,100])
y_train= np.array([60,120,145,195])

def model(x,w,b):
    return x*w+b;

def cost(y,y_hat):
    return np.sum((y-y_hat)**2)

learning_rate=0.000001
def trainning_round(x_train,y_train,w,b,learning_rate):

    y_hat=model(x_train,w,b)
    print(cost(y_train,y_hat))

    w_gradient=-2*x_train.dot(y_train-y_hat)
    b_gradient=-2*np.sum(y_train-y_hat)

    w-=learning_rate*w_gradient
    b-=learning_rate*b_gradient

    return w,b

num_epoch=200
def train(X,Y):

    w=0
    b=0

    #for plt
    ar = np.arange(0, 200, 0.5)
    def f(t):
        return t*w+b

    for i in range(num_epoch):
            w,b=trainning_round(X,Y,w,b,learning_rate)
            plt.plot(ar,f(ar))
            plt.axis([0, 200, 0, 200])

    plt.plot(X, Y, 'ro')

train(x_train,y_train)
plt.show()
```

I have tried some other algorithms but they didn't work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to construct a [mcve], then edit your post accordingly.  Currently, your question is not very clear, and also you haven't provided the data needed to reproduce your problem.  In order to avoid having your question closed, please update to be clearer and more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified some parts.
It is important that you decide appropriate learning_rate and iteration epoch.
That's some difficult. 
So we use a framework like tensorflow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#doesnt work
x_train = np.array([50,100,150,200])
y_train= np.array([150,100,50,0])

#work
# x_train = np.array([30,60,70,100])
# y_train= np.array([60,120,145,195])

def model(x,w,b):
    return x*w+b;

def cost(y,y_hat):
    return np.sum((y-y_hat)**2)/y.size

learning_rate=0.0001
def trainning_round(x_train,y_train,w,b,learning_rate):

    y_hat=model(x_train,w,b)
    j = cost(y_train,y_hat)

    # w_gradient=-2*x_train.dot(y_train-y_hat)
    # b_gradient=-2*np.sum(y_train-y_hat)
    w_gradient=x_train.dot(y_hat-y_train) / y_train.size
    b_gradient=np.sum(y_hat-y_train) / y_train.size

    print(w_gradient, b_gradient)

    w=w-learning_rate*w_gradient
    b=b-learning_rate*b_gradient
    print(j, w,b)
    return w,b

num_epoch=200000
def train(X,Y):

    w=2.1
    b=1.5

    #for plt
    ar = np.arange(0, 200, 0.5)

    for i in range(num_epoch):
        w,b=trainning_round(X,Y,w,b,learning_rate)

    plt.plot(ar,model(ar, w, b))
    plt.axis([0, 300, 0, 200])

    plt.plot(X, Y, 'ro')

train(x_train,y_train)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you Junhee, I tried my code for learning_rate=0.000011 and num_epoch=200000 and it convergates but very slow. Why does we need here 200000+ epoch and in example for x_train = np.array([30,60,70,100])
y_train= np.array([60,120,145,195])  only 200 epoch?

Comment: It depends on the delta which is learning_rate * gradient. Try to print delta value in every iteration.  And check the learning_rate is big or small. The learning_rate should be not too big nor too small. Both cases can't be converged. And the iteration count is also important. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an adaptive learning rate:

```
def optimal_learning_rate(X,y,W):
    grad = -np.matmul(X.T,y-np.matmul(X,W))/len(y)
    hessian = np.matmul(X.T,X)
    return np.matmul(grad.T,grad)/np.matmul(np.matmul(grad.T,hessian,grad)
```

This implementation is for a multidimensional X